# arrays and index

Tags: c++, arrays, flags

How can I enter numbers into an array such that duplicate entries are ignored?

For example, if I put `6` and then `3` into the array, attempting to then insert `6` into the the array should cause `6` to be rejected (since it is already in the array).

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int x,y;
  int number;
  int arr[5];

  for (x=0; x<5; )
  {
    cout<<"enter a number:"<<endl;
    cin>>number;
    bool replace = True;
    for (y=0; y<x; y++)
    {
       if (number != arr[y])
       {
         cout << "try next time" << endl;
         replace = False;
         break;
       }
    }

    if (replace)
    {
      arr[x] = number;
      x++;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @jboy - if this is homework, please add the appropriate tag by editing your question. The community will also be much more receptive if you post code showing what you have tried so far.

Comment: ok ill show my code help me pls..

Comment: I reformatted the code and noted 2 things - 1. You didn't cut/paste because the indenting is invalid. 2. There are extraneous 'flags' lines that will cause non-compiles.  Fix these two items and then we can help to figure it out.

Comment: What is 'False', 'True' ?  Posting uncompilable and ever-changing code is very annoying.

Comment: @jboy: Steve is actually helping you when editing your code. Try to learn from it. If this really is an exam question... Wow..

Comment: @Steve - mea culpa - I see the OP has no grasp of c++ and I jump around too much and so recommended boolean... True/False instead of bool... true/false

Comment: @KevinDTimm - no problem.  Seems like OP needs to ask his professor for some C++ bootstrapping guidance.  Let's hope this is not the final exam.

Comment: @Steve - If you follow my post exactly, you'll see that I create a running program.  But I think the bootstrapping is what's necessary as the lack of knowledge is a huge barrier to understanding any of this.

Comment: Eh? You talk as if everybody knows what you're talking about. What is your question?

Comment: He's assuming all of us will copy paste the code, compile and run it I guess :p

Comment: @Etienne - this relates to a prolonged effort to get a decent question asked earlier today.  Code is at least formatted properly and compilable now :-) The problem of "please tell me the code" remains.

Comment: @jboy - what do you mean by 'rejected'.  How are you rejecting duplicate inputs?

Comment: There are 2 failures in the code (but yes, it would be better if the original question was asked)

Comment: Is it that number is misspelled?

Comment: @KLee1 - no, that's just a label.

Comment: @steve- i mean you cant inut the same number again that what it is..

Comment: Folks, I know this kind of thing is both rude and all too common, but we want Stack Overflow to be a welcoming place. Accordingly, you should  **politely** refuse to answer such questions. I'm looking at Blender and rerun in particular; Frustrated gets a pass for being silly.

Answer (score 4):

`std::set<int>` would do what you want.  This is not indexable, though.

You could use [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) to give you random access and enforce uniqueness on the same underlying list of values.

btw - asking directly for code is not recommended practice.

Comment: what i mean is if you type the same number again it will deny becoz the number you imput is already in the index,this is my code :

Comment: @jboy - The word you're looking for is 'because'

Comment: im just a student and i want to figured out whats wrong in my codes so i can fix it,just this time pls...

Comment: @jboy - posting code in comments is tough to make clear and hard to find for new responders.  Paste the code into your question text, select it and then format it by pressing the '101010' icon.  Thanks.

Comment: @steve- where can i find that icon?

Comment: @jboy - you should see it above the top of the textbox when you are editing your question.  There are 'quote' and 'URL' icons too

Comment: pls teach me the missing code

Comment: This is not a 'homework for hire' site.  You need to do the work yourself.  What's not working in your code?  Flow of control looks reasonable apart from the strange 'flags' which obviously won't compile.  I suggest you forget about this question and post a new one that clearly describes what is not working from your point of view, with compilable code.  "It is not working" is an invitation to more downvotes.  "I wind up with duplicate entries" is better.  Add more output inside your loops to dump the full array on each loop.  This is what programmers do.

Comment: @steve-how?just teach me step by step how so i can solve it on my own..

Comment: the codes now run but if i input the same number it still run,it supose to reject the number if i put the same number.

Answer (score 4):

you have too many `x++`'s and you don't preset `arr` (maybe more style than error)

how do you know it's not working?
 (put some debug code inside of `if (number == arr[y])` and `if (replace`)

Comment: @Steve - thanks :{) - hopefully some props for actually posting the correct solution also (twice)

Answer (score 2):

What you really want is a `set`.  Sets cannot contain duplicate elements.

[Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/) is a reference to the set in C++.

Just use the set as a container for your numbers. When you try to add a duplicate, it will be automatically rejected.

Comment: can you give me the codes?c++ for codeblocks?

Comment: @jboy, no.  Sorry.  Just use the set as a container for your numbers.  When you try to add a duplicate, it will be automatically rejected.

Comment: @jboy: The code for this assignment *should not* be that IDE-dependent. If it is, you're probably doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want an array but a datastructure called Hashtable for that;

Alternatively, you might want to look up a datastructure called associative array.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use arrays for this. You should use, for example, std::set. Or, if you need to have an array as your data structure, you could encapsulate the array (e.g. realized through std::vector) in a class and define specific functions to access the array elements. Additionally, you could hold a std::set to provide a fast check for existing elements.

Comment: It's homework - pointing him towards std:set is counterproductive in that he's doing what the assignment tells him.  hopefully std:set will come into play next week :)

Comment: @KevinDTimm: I dunno, it's already December. I would have thought most schools would be in exam mode by now. `std:set` might not come until next term in January.

Comment: You're right, they are.  But to most college students, January is next week (even if next term is a month away)

Comment: but here in us its our exam week and this is our exam about array,make a progrm in arrays and this is wat our teacher thought us

Answer (score 1):

Should be :

```
int arr[5] = {0,0,0,0,0};
```

Remove the x++ from the following line:

```
for (x=0;x<5;x++)
```

Then:

```
bool replace=true;
for (y=0;y<x;y++)
{
   if (number == arr[y])
   {
      replace=false;
      break;
   }
}

if (replace)
{
      arr[x]=number;
      x++;
}
```

Finally, remove the :

```
else if(number == arr[x])
{
    arr[x]=number;

cout << "try next time"<<endl;
}
```

You can insert :

```
cout << "try next time"<<endl;
```

before the

```
replace=false;
```

Comment: it run but without xtt in for (x=0 its error

Comment: sorry, that doesn't help (especially since the code in your post IS NOT what you are using - it would never compile)

Comment: i try it but it was errors,do i also delete the flgs?

Comment: #include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
int x,y;
int number;
int arr[5];

for (x=0;x<=4;x++)
{
    cout<<"enter nmber"<<endl;
    cin>>number;
for (y=0;x<=y;y++)
{
    if (number == arr[x])
    {
    arr[x]=number;

    }

else if(number == arr[x])
{
    arr[x]=number;

}
}


}
return 0;

}
heres my code in my compiler

Comment: so what are those things ht is missing...

Comment: so whats the right code?

Comment: update the original post - what you have in the comments is indecipherable.

Comment: i edit it and it say the tru and false was not declared in the scoop

Comment: 1) it should be bool true/false not boolean True/False.  2) post your REAL code in the original post so it can be read.

Comment: i post it,its still error,how to make it run?

Comment: stll the true and false is not on the scoop

Comment: I don't think I can help you any more.  When I follow the instructions above, I create a compilable executable which conforms to your requirements.  Since you don't post the changed code when you report more errors, I don't know what you're attempting to compile.  Since the code is being modified I would recommend that each iteration be posted on pastebin and pointed to from your post.

Comment: @jboy: and the link to that question is...?

Comment: @Frustrated - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431836/arrays-and-index-2/4431896

Answer (score 0):

Take out the x++ in the for loop,  That way you will only increment that count when you enter a new number.

Also, if you want to only run the loop five times, your outer for loop should be only to x<5.

All in all your outer loop should read:

```
for (x=0;x<5;)
```

Comment: He only gets half the modifications he's supposed to get from the OP (these are the 2 that have been missed, referred to in my comment above and one of them in my answer below - I was hoping he would note the mistakes in his 'code review')

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at where you increment `x`.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you want to read in a sequence of numbers eliminating any duplicates.
It also appears that the maximum number of unique numbers is **5**.

```
int n = 0;  /* The number of unique numbers read in so far */
for {;;}
  cout << "enter nmber" << endl;
  cin >> number;
  for (x=0; x < n; ++x) {
    if (number == arr[x]) goto L1;  /* I love messing with peoples head by using this goto */
  }
  arr[n] = number;
  ++n;
  if (n == 5) break;
L1:
  continue;
}
```

Comment: Please read the FAQ - http://stackoverflow.com/faq